# Find the path to rust source file that invoked a macro (within the macro) on rust stable

Tags: rust, macros

I have a working macro (shown below) on rust nightly. I would like to be able to do the same on rust stable.

I use proc_macro2's Span to get the name of the source file where the macro was used.

```rust
#![feature(proc_macro_span)]

// uses are here... removed for brevity

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn flow_function(_attr: TokenStream, implementation: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // Get the full path to the file where the macro was used, and join the relative filename from
    // the macro's attributes, to find the path to the function's definition file
    let span = Span::call_site();
    let implementation_file_path = span.source_file().path().canonicalize()
        .expect("the 'flow' macro could not get the full file path of the file where it was invoked");

    let mut definition_file_path = implementation_file_path.clone();
    definition_file_path.set_extension("toml");
    //print!("file_path = {}", file_path.display());

    let function_definition = load_function_definition(&definition_file_path);

    // Build the output token stream with generated code around original supplied code
    generate_code(implementation, implementation_file_path,
                  function_definition, definition_file_path)
}
```

Is there any way to do this (get the source file path where the macro was used) on rust stable?

Comment: Does the [`file` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.file.html) work for you?

Comment: The file!() macro will give you (always) the source file where the macro I'd defined, not the file where it is used, or "invoked"

Comment: I'm not sure that's currently possible on stable Rust. I faced similar issues when writing [`include_display_mode_tex`](https://crates.io/crates/include_display_mode_tex). In the documentation, I mentioned similar projects. Notably, [`include_dir`](https://crates.io/crates/include_dir) utilize environment variables.

Comment: Yeh, I'm watching the tracking issue for it. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54725